# Content-Type error while consuming a SOAP1.2 service

Tags: web-services, soap, content-type, soap1.2

I am having trouble consuming a SOAP1.2 service. I am getting this error:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException:Unsupported 
Content-Type: text/xml Supported ones are: [application/soap+xml] 
at 
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode
(StreamSOAPCodec.java:220)
```

Here are the WSDL details and the generated Java clients:

```
<wsdl:operation name="redeem">
<soap12:operation 
       soapAction="http://org.comp.PartnerService
       /PartnerConnectorResponder/redeem" style="document" />

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Client (WSImport Generated)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
* This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
* JAX-WS RI 2.2.8
* Generated source version: 2.2
* 
*/

@WebServiceClient(name = "PartnerService", targetNamespace = 
"http://tempuri.org/", wsdlLocation = "/jaxws/PartnerService_1.wsdl")
public class PartnerService extends Service
{
   @WebEndpoint(name = "WSHttpBinding_PartnerConnectorResponder")
   public PartnerConnectorResponder getConnectorResponder() {
       return super.getPort(
              new QName("http://tempuri.org/", 
              "PartnerConnectorResponder"), 
              ,PartnerConnectorResponder.class);
   }
}

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Invocation: [Pseudo code]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
fun redeem() {
   var soapClient:PartnerConnectorResponder = getConnectorResponder()
   var bindingProvider:BindingProvider=(soapClient asBindingProvider)

   bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml")

   //Also tried lower 't' in type but no luck
   //bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("Content-type", "application/soap+xml")

   bindingProvider.redeem();
}
```

The code is somehow setting the default content type of SOAP 1.1 (text/xml). Even after I manually set the content type, it still fails with the same error.

I would really appreciate any inputs as I have been stuck for a week now.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding the following property to the SOAP Client:
AddressingFeature(true)